# How to Run console application on azure Function

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I created a chat bot for twitch(locally)(.net core app 3.1). It works fine on local.

I want to work it 7/24. I saw azure functions maybe works for it.

how can i do that ? Is It possible?

My app works forever.

and this is my app u can check it : [link](https://github.com/sydneyfunnelAIO/sydneyfunnelbot)

Comment: Yes that’s possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/run-console-apps-on-azure-functions/

Comment: should i use http trigger ?

Comment: @crystalcyber Yes, you can use http trigger, but you need to notice the function should not be too large. Because azure function has a timeout limit.

Comment: @crystalcyber And dont stay in the logic of function for too long.

Comment: Hi, have you work it out?

Comment: If you want to run 7/24, you could try webjob.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use http trigger to achieve what you what. But you need to know azure function have a time out limit, so please dont stay in the logic in your function for too long. Have a look fo this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Remember azure function should be small and fast, dont make it be too large.:)

Comment: @crystalcyber run 7 h every day? You can use timetrigeer